# How do we know the position of fixed point in this Q?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, vectors, proof-explanation

Q: A particle moves on a given straight line with a constant speed v. At a certain time it is at a point $P$ on its straight line path. $O$ is a fixed point. Show that (OP×v)is independent of the position P.

My solution:

I considered the axis to be X-axis I.e as 1D motion. Points P & O on it. O to be the starting point from where the particle started.

$OP = x$ $\hat{\mathbf{i}}$

$OP$ X $v$ = vi X x$\hat{i}$(OP) = 0 since $ixi$ =$0$.

[image]

Solution from my textbook:(Different way than mine)

[image]

My questions regarding this solution :

Q1: Why did they consider point O to be at a distance y axis ? Since about point O , no description related to its position is given.
Also , Can we consider point O to be at any point ? Like somewhere in Z axis.

Q2: The Q says that we have to find $OPxV$ independent of the position P. Then , In this solution = $-y*v*k$. We have $(OPxV) $dependant upon the magnitude of y & v & direction k. The value will change w/ time.

Comment: Constant speed $\vec v = v\,\vec i$ means $v$ is constant and $\vec i$ doesn't change. Fixed point $O$ means $y$ doesn't change, so $-yv\vec k$ doesn't change either. A point and a line define a unique plane $(\vec i, \vec j)$ in which $OP$ always lies.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it say that O lies somewhere on the line through which the particle moves. You have assumed this, so you have only proved the question for that special case; not for the general case that the question is asking about.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes & nether does it say it lies somewhere outside the line. Now , when I solved it first. I assumed it to be on the line. The solution of textbook assume it to be outside the line. We both had same answers. I have explained this already in my Q with the related difficulties I have regarding it.

Comment: So if I asked you to prove for example that all rectangles have diagonals that are of equal length, and you proved it only for squares, would you consider that a complete proof?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis No , I wouldn’t.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis How would u proof that taking point(O) at a distance of y along y axis is a point which can be considered to be used for general proof ?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis What general case does the Q ask about ? I think it’s not specified.

Comment: From any point O in space outside of the particle's trajectory line you can draw the shortest connecting line between O and the trajectory. This is perpendicular to the trajectory. Use this as one of your coordinate axes, e.g. the y-axis, and let another coordinate axis be parallel to the trajectory. You are free to choose your coordinate axes because they are all equivalent through rotation/translation.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I know this because it is already there in the solution of textbook. The Q is , how do you prove this to be the general case & not special case. Why not choose y-x , z , z-x axis ?

Comment: It does not matter what you call your axes. The point is that the vector OP decomposes into the sum of two parts, one part parallel to the trajectory, and one part perpendicular to it. The cross product wipes out the part parallel to the trajectory (which depends on time) leaving you only with a constant part, which depends on the distance to the trajectory but not the distance to the moving particle itself.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Could u please write an answer , if will be much more clearer then. Right now , it’s broken points with comments.

Comment: Q1: Distance y can be any number, but it doesn't change in time.

Q2: Yes, we can consider O to be at any point.

Q3: The magnitude of y & v & direction k do not change with time.

Q4: The solution given in the text is fine.

Q5: The solution you wrote only deals with a particular case. It isn't correct.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Hii , thanks a lot for answering my questions. I’m having difficulty understanding as to why (the reason) solution textbook is the general case ? Could u pls elaborate on that. Thanks.

Comment: The given line (path of the particle) and point O define a plane (if O is on the line then any plane containing the line will do). In that plane we choose axis i parallel to the given line and axis j perpendicular to it.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the line is $ P(t) = P_0 + t v $

$OP(t) \times v = ((P_0 - O) + t v ) \times v = (P_0 - O) \times v + t (v \times v) = (P_0 - O) \times v $

Thus the cross product is independent of $t$.

Comment: What do you think about the answer I wrote & the one textbook gave.

Comment: All answers are pretty much the same.

Comment: If u see the comments & I also asked on chat group , they say we cannot place point O on the path where particle is moving I.e my solution. But they’re also unable to tell why is the solution of textbook the general case. Could you please answer upon that as well. It will be a huge help in understanding.

Comment: Point $O$ can be any where in space, and that's why the textbook solution is more general than yours.  In your solution the cross product will be zero, while in the textbook answer (and also my solution) it is in general a non-zero constant vector.